# How to make a pointer point to the element of an array?

Tags: c, pointers

I want the character pointer b to point to the array elements and then send b to function to do some processing on this elements.

```
 unsigned char arr[]={ }; //it has some values
 unsigned char *b ;
   for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
    b=&arr[i];}       // here how can deal with b
  for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
      printf("%u\n  ",b[i]);      
      }
 double *output = (double*) function1(b);
//-----------
void *function1(unsigned char *b){
   // some processing
}
```

Comment: `b = arr + i` is a common way to write `b = & arr[i]`.

Comment: What do you mean "here how can deal with b"?  After you've made the assignment, b points to one of the array elements.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: In this way that I used, when print the values of b I get on 0! and I was expecting to get the arr values so I think there is a problem in the assignment or ?!

Comment: You have one loop that goes through 10 iterations, setting `b` to a different value in each iteration, `b=&arr[i];`. When that loop is done, `b` has the last value it was given, the value in the last iteration, so `b=&arr[9];`. After that, you have another loop that goes through 10 iterations, each time printing `b[i]`. `b` still has its last value, so these print `b[9]`. Finally, you have one single function call, `function1(b);`, which calls `function1` once with the last value of `b`…

Comment: … If you want to do something while `b` is pointing to an array element, do something **while** `b` is pointing to an array element. Write **one** loop that contains multiple statements: Assign a value to `b`, print `b[i]` if you wish, and call `function1` all inside that one loop.

Comment: In future questions, always provide a [mre]. That should include **complete** code that other people can compile and execute with no changes or additions. for example, it should have `#include <stdio.h>` because the code calls `printf`, and it should not have `unsigned char arr[]={ };`; it should have actual working code with sample values, lke `unsigned char arr[]={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};`. And the code should be inside a function, such as `main`, so that it can be compiled and executed without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not good at c and I don't exactly know what are you trying to do, but a pointer will point only to one element. If you want to point to the array, just point to the first element and use brackets [] to process its inner elements.

```
b = arr
```

which is equal to

```
b = &arr[0]
```

You don't need the first loop.